# “Der Mann wird alt und ist verknallt.” – meaning of “verknallt”

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

I am trying to understand the lyrics of Rolf Zuckowski’s song *Achterbahn,* whose very last part says ([full text](https://www.musik-fuer-dich.de/sites/default/files/songtexte/3303-achterbahn.pdf)):

> Die Kinder groß, das Haus wird leer,
>   auf einmal Zeit für soviel mehr.
>   Zu zweit allein, ganz ungeübt,
>   das lernt man schon, wenn man sich liebt.
>
> Der Mann wird alt und ist verknallt.

I understand all the words, but the last line isn’t clear: The man gets old and is .. infatuated? crazy? in love? I’m stuck on *verknallt.*

Comment: Infatuated is a good match, but a slightly higher register, I tink. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verknallt

Comment: "Verknallt" is not a word typically used for an old man. So either Zuckowski wanted to emphasize the silliness or the freshness of the old man's love, or he simply needed an adjective that rhymes with "alt".

Answer (score 3):

"Verknallt = in love" is correct. It's usually used for the initial fresh love, pink-tinted glasses phase. "Verliebt" / possibly unreturned, new and not-yet-matured feeling as opposed to "lieben" / stable, deep long term emotion.